# How do I connect a bluetooth mouse with a Surface Pro 4

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, microsoft-surface

I have a Logitech Bluetooth mouse, it comes with a USB plug that goes into the USB slot. The problem is that the Surface Pro only has 1 USB port. Can the Surface Pro connect to the Logitech mouse with its own Bluetooth connection, so I can free up the only USB port?

Comment: SP4 has built-in Bluetooth support.  Sounds like the mouse ain’t Bluetooth if it requires the receiver to function.  But yourself a USB Hub to solve the port problem

Comment: Agree... turn the one USB port into many with a USB Hub.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the Surface Pro connect to the Logitech mouse with its own Bluetooth connection, so I can free up the only USB port?

Yes, it can. Here's how to do it on any Windows 10 PC, including the Surface Pro:

1. Open start menu and start typing "Bluetooth and other devices settings" without the quotes, then select it from the search result:

[Bluetooth and other devices settings search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0n5L.png)

2. Turn on your Logitech Bluetooth mouse and put it in pairing mode (on mice like the MX Master or Anywhere MX 2 and later, you press connect at the bottom to do this)
3. Select the "Add Bluetooth or other device" option on your Surface Pro:

[Add Bluetooth or other device option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI4n0.png)

4. Select the "Bluetooth" option, your Surface Pro will begin searching for your Logitech Bluetooth mouse, once it shows up in the list, select it.
5. Windows will automatically install the necessary drivers and you should be good to go :)

To get the most out of your logitech mouse, don't forget to install the Logitech Options application on your Surface Pro. Just search google for Logitech Options.